# want to start installed third party navigation app through my application

Tags: android

Through my application i want to start another navigation app.
which accept destination coordinate/Address as parameter.
Is it possible?
Is there any app which accept destination coordinate/Address.

Answer (score 1):

> Through my application i want to start another navigation app. which accept destination coordinate/Address as parameter. Is it possible?

You would have to contact the developers of whatever navigation app you wanted to start and ask them how to do this.